# print_r SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to print out an SQL statement but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.  It is not printing out any results just simply the SQL statement itself.

```
<?php

    $date = new DateTime();
    $ts = $date->getTimestamp();

    $currentDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $ts));


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'events' where 'date_start' = '$currentDate'";

    print_r($sql);

?>
```

Comment: You should start from here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Making a variable called `$sql` doesn't make it SQL. You also need to use backticks for table names and/or column names. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php and then look at prepared statements for your choosing driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'events' where 'date_start' = '$currentDate'";


$result= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


print_r($result);
```

use mysql_query and now try hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks  a bunch man!

Comment: Please don't suggest that people use `mysql_` functions. The library is deprecated, and has been removed from the newest versions of PHP

Answer (score 0):

remove single quota `'` from table name and column name, or replace with (`) :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events where date_start = '$currentDate'";
```

or:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `events` where `date_start` = '$currentDate'";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the query hasn't even executed yet.

You need to use mysql_query or mysqli_query(which ever one you're using) to execute it and then fetch the result.

```
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM events where date_start = '".$currentDate"' ";
$result  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result  = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
print_r($result  );
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score -1):

**If your time is integer than you can use this.**

```
<?php

        $date = new DateTime();
        $ts = $date->getTimestamp();

        $currentDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $ts));


       $sql = "SELECT * FROM events where date_start = '$currentDate'";

        print_r($sql);

    ?>
```

Comment: He wants to run the query. Your answer doesn't do this.